# open camera calibration accuracy

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I am calibrating my camera and I get quite bad results. As of now, I blame that my camera is bad or I am doing something wrong. The main functions I use are: **findChessboardCorners**, **cornerSubPix**, **findCirclesGrid**, **calibrateCamera** and **solvePnP** (as very well described in the opencv documentation for camera calibration)

So I started to evaluate how the algorithm for camera calibration works if I add 'perfect' data. I used 3D CAD modelling software (Rhinoceros3D) and modelled my grids with absolute accuracy, i.e. square sizes and the distances between are exactly 10 mm . My calibration pattern lies on OXY plane. Because 3D cad software has perspective view, I can easily render the results on the screen as it is in the reality. So I generated images as I would capture them in the real world. This scenario is the perfect case - the pattern is absolutely precise, there is no distortion and there is no camera in the world to produce such good results.

Chessboard 8x10
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9zbzk6bqekih8il/AADUZvxwd5PdmGXauCJSHFMwa?dl=0

and

Asymmetric grid 4 x 11
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9abr79py4z9hf3x/AABj0ez5_bxL4rsFLjxKwjsma?dl=0

My next step is to calibrate camera. I passed the images and from calibrateCamera function I get error of 0.115208 px for chessboard and 0.030177 px for asymmetric grid.

Then what I need to do is to evaluate how good the calibration is. For the same set of images I use solvePnP ( used solvePnPRansac with the same results) to locate where the camera is. I made clear solve - no initial guess for the camera position (as this is a new position in the space of the camera). Using rot and trans of the results, I construct a cartesian coordinate system, pass a ray from camera origin, through the UNDISTORTED points and intersect with plane OXY. 
Ideally I would expect these lines will intersect the plane very accurately ( in points (0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 0) etc.).

The problem is that I get significant offset of around 0.15 mm, which means that locating my camera in 3D is wrong. I want to use this as base to do 'camera - projector calibration', but if I get such a big error in the 'perfect' scenario, this will never get good results with real camera/projector.

Another test which I did was:
1. For every image after we have calibrationMatrix and deviation coefficients, locate the camera position using solvePnP.
2. Intersect only first point of the detected corners in the pattern. ( It should intersect 0XY in (0, 0) )
3. Evaluate standard deviation of the distances for all of these points to the origin (0, 0) - LOCATION accuracy
4. Evaluate standard deviation of the distances for all these points to their average point - SYSTEMATIC accuracy

The problem is that for LOCATION accuracy I get error 0.165423 mm and for SYSTEMATIC accuracy I get error 0.035441 mm.

These errors are two high . I would expect for both LOCATION and SYSTEMATIC accuracy to get something like 0.0001 mm for the data set provided.

My question is - Can someone test the images from the links in their implementation and let me know what are the results? May be I miss something in my implementation, but I truly believe that we should get 'perfect' results when we provide 'perfect' data.

I will be really grateful for the help.

P.S. - I am using opencv 2.4.10. Has anything been improved in 3.0 in these algorithms?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you account for the fact that OpenCV uses Z forward, Y down, unlike Rhino?

Comment: Well. I don't understand why this makes any sense in this case. If you just take a look - they are just images from a pinhole camera model. The fact that is from Rhino, doesn't really matter. Also, I am not talking about error in flipping direction, but the accuracy in the end results. The fact that it calibrates means that it works. The problem is why doesn't converge to really small value.